# What's the best way to find all 'cycles/cliques' in a matrix in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a square matrix with a bunch of 0's and 1's, like this example:

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6

1   0 1 0 1 0 0
2   1 0 0 1 0 0
3   0 0 0 0 0 0
4   1 1 0 0 0 0
5   0 0 0 0 0 1
6   0 0 0 0 1 0
```

We can consider this an adjacency matrix of sorts, with 6 vertices, and all diagonal elements are necessarily 0. And of course, the matrix must be symmetric about the diagonal.

What is the most efficient way, in R, given a bunch of matrices like this, of varying sizes, to find all 'cliques' in each matrix and give the members of each clique? (By 'clique' I mean a set of vertices each of which has an edge going to each other vertex in the set) For example, in the above matrix, there are two cliques; denoting the vertices by the row/column numbers, the cliques are (1, 2, 4) and (5, 6). So, for output, I want a list of all vertices (row or column names) in each clique, for all cliques in that matrix. And I want to do this for a large number of matrices of varying sizes (though all would be square matrices). Any ideas on what the best way to do this is?

I had been thinking of using a for loop within a for loop, but for the fact that the size of possible cliques is indeterminate (but at most can equal the number of rows/columns in the matrix) makes me think I may need to use a while loop, though I'm not sure how precisely.

I will paste some code I just wrote that was supposed to do what I've described, with the list 'cliquelist' containing all cliques in the matrix by the end of the loop. The adjacency matrix is called 'mat.'

```
cliquelist <- NULL

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(mat)){
    if(mat[i,j]==1){
      clique <- c(i, j)
      pool <- j:ncol(mat)
      while(length(pool)>0) {
        add <- which(mat[,pool[1]]==1)
        if(length(add)==0){
          pool <- NULL
        }else{
          pool <- pool[which(!pool %in% add)]
          clique <- c(clique, add)
        }
      }
      cliquelist[length(cliquelist)+1] <- clique
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure this code has some bugs in it; I have not figured out what they are since it is still running (after many minutes) on the example matrix I showed above, so I suspect there's an infinite loop in their somewhere.

But there are several problems with it that even make me disinclined to go back and debug it. 1) Most obviously, it will add each clique to the list as many times as there are elements in the list, so there's a lot of redundancy. 2) It doesn't filter out smaller cliques that are subsumed within bigger cliques. So, if a clique consists of vertices 1, 3, and 5, then something like the code above will return (1, 3), (1, 5), (3, 5), (1, 3, 5), etc. But I only want unique cliques not subsumed in larger cliques. I am wondering if there is a different, more efficient way to do this in R.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: you want `library(igraph)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `igraph` library is custom made for graph analysis. With dat as the name of your matrix:

```
library(igraph)
z <- graph.adjacency(dat)
cluster_walktrap(z)

IGRAPH clustering walktrap, groups: 3, mod: 0.38
+ groups:
  $`1`
  [1] "X5" "X6"

  $`2`
  [1] "X1" "X2" "X4"

  $`3`
  [1] "X3"
```

Here's a plot:

```
plot(z)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had come across the igraph vignette but didn't read far enough into it to find cluster_walktrap. Precisely what I was looking for though.